# How to render screen aligned rectangles the same way as point-sprites in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'd like to render rectangles aligned to the screen axis but without using any fancy thing such as triangles or fans...
I searched the web but only found exemples using triangles... (and eventually one using scissor rectangles but it would be too slow if I render many of them, especially on older versions)

I *know* triangles are what modern hardware are the best at rendering but I don't see how it could be faster than doing something (theorically) like:

```
for (i=y; i<y+h; i++) {
    for (j=x; j<x+w; j++) {
        executeFragmentShader(j, i);
    }
} //x, y, w and h being the rectangle's data
```

I'm asking if there is a way in OpenGL to render rectangle like point sprites just by specifying one vertex and the dimensions as you do with gl_PointSize.

In the case it's not possible that way, how do video accelerated softwares like internet browser or other desktop apps render rectangular areas?
Do they use triangles?

Comment: You can emit two triangles from a single vertex if you use geometry shaders. But, I must stress, geometry shaders never really improve performance any in this sort of scenario. You would get better performance by drawing 4 indexed vertices and billboarding them in a vertex shader.

Answer (score 3):

They use triangles, arranged like so:

[image: Square composed of two triangles]

If you don't care about the depth buffer values, then you can render quads by not doing any transformations in your vertex shader (or, if using the old `glMatrix` functions, using an identity projection and modelview matrix); `(-1, -1)` will be the bottom-left corner of the screen, while `(1,1)` ill be the top-right corner. Optionally, you can use an orthographic projection matrix to pass in pixel coordinates, or something else.

If you need depth values, or need to use world-space coordinates, look up billboarding; there's plenty of tutorials on how to do it.

Keep in mind that modern 3D games draw hundreds of thousands of projected triangles each frame, but only a few HUD elements, which are almost always simple textured rectangles. Guess which case GPU vendors optimize for.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer,  
but I believe (tell me if I'm wrong) that rendering a point sprite is faster than rendering two triangles (that you have to rasterize).  Then, the same should be achievable for rectangles **aligned and facing the screen**, right?  So is it a mistake from the every programmers (kind of unlikely) or is it simply not possible in OpenGL (kind of disapointing) ?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer. Are you claiming that point sprites are rendered as two triangles? That's not something that the GL specification covers - it is certainly possible to render aliased point sprites as two triangles without violating anything but it's not the only way it can be done. Anti-aliased point sprites on the other hand are rasterized a completely different way (as circles).

Comment: @Lewin Points can only be rendered as squares, but you can possibly use a fragment shader with `discard` to fake non-square rectangles. Otherwise, the two-triangles approach is the only way to form a rectangle. Points may be faster, but unless you are rendering thousands of objects, the difference is most likely negligible.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Sorry for the confusion. The first sentence was in response to the last two sentences in the question; my answer doesn't reference point sprites at all.